Understand the proof for the following claim in convex analysis
Let $C_1$ and $C_2$ be convex sets. Show that
$$C_1 \cap \operatorname{ri}(C_2) \neq\emptyset \iff \operatorname{ri}(C_1 \cap \operatorname{aff}(C_2))\cap \operatorname{ri}(C_2) \neq\emptyset.$$
The proof only follows the "$\implies$" direction as the other direction is pretty straightforward. It's as follows:
Let $x \in C_1 \cap \operatorname{ri}(C_2)$ and $\bar{x} \in \operatorname{ri}(C_1 \cap \operatorname{aff}(C_2))$. Let $L$ be the line segment connecting $x$ and $\bar{x}$.
Then $L$ belongs to $C_1 \cap \operatorname{aff}(C_2)$ since both of its endpoints belong to $C_1 \cap \operatorname{aff}(C_2)$. Hence, by the Line Segment Principle, all points of $L$ except possibly $x$, belong to $\operatorname{ri}(C_1 \cap \operatorname{aff}(C_2))$ ......
The proof continues on to which I can follow what comes after assuming I can accept what was written above. The main question would by where/how exactly did the author use Line segment principle. To my knowledge, you would need to pick $x$ in a convex $C$ and $\bar{x}$ in it's closure $\operatorname{cl}(C)$, then we can claim that all the points (except maybe without $\bar{x}$) is contained in $\operatorname{ri}(C)$. I am having some trouble connecting the dots and any help or insights is appreciated.
Cheers.

You might be misunderstanding the line segment principle (though, this is the first time I've heard it named so). If you have a point $x$ in the relative interior of $C$, and $y$ in $C$, then the semi-open line segment $[x, y)$, i.e. including $x$, not including $y$ is contained in $\operatorname{ri}C$. It has nothing to do with the closure of $C$, and the version you stated would not work in general (e.g. your two points could be adjacent vertices in a closed, convex polygon in $\Bbb{R}^2$).
